# Using PHP, web scrape main url for all images, redisplay onto another website

Tags: php, file, curl, scrape

Interestingly, I have not been able to find a working example of this. Using php, I'm trying to scrape/re display all the images of a given url, onto another website. I know how to do this with text, but images, I'm not sure. Anyone know of a good working example? I get how to grab all contents, but not specifically just the images. ex this does the whole page:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL,         
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Picture_of_the_day");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
echo $result;
?>
```

Thanks much. -Wilson

*ideally actually this would just grab the first image, such as in the example above. But I won't get ahead of myself, just trying to get this function down.

Comment: Try [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a file to save the result.

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'a+');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, function ($dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow) {
});
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 8);

curl_exec($ch);

$error = curl_error($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
$end_size = $begin_size + curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD);
Log::info('end_size='.$end_size);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Oh wow, you're amazing Kris thank you! Your solution is the ONLY one that I have been able to get to be very close to what I'm trying to do. okay so if you go to this link, you'll see how this is functioning. http://www.wilsonschlamme.com/wiki.php    BUT, what I'd really love to do, is only show the headline text of the random image, and the image itself. But I'm actually getting quite close to figuring out how to do this sort of function, SO THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH. Nothing else was working.

Comment: yeah, glad it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can add /use **[PHP DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)** function to parsing your scrape result.

add this following script right after your code

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($result); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);    

//get all images 
$images = $xpath->query ('//img/@src');
$img = array();
foreach ( $images as $image) {
    $img[] = $image->nodeValue;
}
print_r($img);
```

** Edited Part 
[image]

Try to change your CURL code with this one

```
$url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Picture_of_the_day';
$curl       = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); //untuk https
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);//untuk https
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'gzip');
$html = curl_exec($curl);
if(curl_error($curl)){ 
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    $result = ''; //return empty if error
}
else {
    $result = $html;
}
```

Comment: hm couldn't quite get that to work, getting an error. syntax, unexpected "is" T_STRING on line 10. this is what I'm using now with what you added

Comment: <?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL,         
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Picture_of_the_day");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($result); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);    

//get all images 
$images = $xpath->Something is wrong ('//img/@src');
$img = array();
foreach ( $images as $image) {
    $img[] = $image->nodSomething is wrongue;
}
print_r($img);
?>

Comment: Ryan, I really appreciate your answers. I am a little confused about how exactly to format everything, I admit I'm super super new to php. Trying to understand what you mean, I took the bottom code answer, and then put in the first code answer after. Which gave me this kind of result, but no image. Array ( [0] => //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/16/Illustrated_War_News%2C_Dec._23%2C_1914%2C_page_38%2C_right_side_-_British_Gunners_in_Action_at_the_Front.jpg/300px-Illustrated_War_News%2C_Dec._23%2C_1914%2C_page_38%2C_rig

Comment: this is the exact code I'm trying now: <?php
$url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Picture_of_the_day';
$curl       = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); //untuk https
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);//untuk https
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'gzip');

Comment: $html = curl_exec($curl);
if(curl_error($curl)){ 
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    $result = ''; //return empty if error
}
else {
    $result = $html;
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($result); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);    

//get all images 
$images = $xpath->query ('//img/@src');
$img = array();
foreach ( $images as $image) {
    $img[] = $image->nodeValue;
}
print_r($img);
?>

Comment: you've got an array consist of image urls from that wikipedia url.. Simply way you just need to <img src="url"> to display an image. If you want to display all just make a loop from that $Img array

Comment: hm. would it look something like this? foreach ($images as $image) {
echo "<img src='imagesDirectory/$image.jpg'> <br>";     haven't been able to get that to work yet, but that's the best example I've found so far for dealing with arrays and img src url

Comment: sorry for being so clueless. this is by far the most difficult thing I've ever attempted

Comment: just use echo '<img src="'.$image.'">'; inside your foreach loop. if it's worked you can mark my answer as accepted.